# vb.net mysql Last_Insert_ID causing double DB entry?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, last-insert-id

I can't figure out why I am getting a double DB entry every time a subroutine is executed.  I think I have an idea and I think it is something simple, but I'm not sure how to fix it.  Thanks for any assistance anyone can provide.

Here is my datasource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource id="sqlvoted" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Mym6pConnection %>"
ProviderName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And the relevant portion of the sub:

```
sqlvoted.InsertParameters.Clear()
sqlvoted.InsertCommand = "INSERT INTO urls (url,likes,mlsid,sitename) VALUES ('" & url & "','" & firstlike.ToString & "','" & newmlsid & "','" & sitename & "');SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()"
sqlvoted.Insert()
```

And the event handler:

```
Protected Sub sqlvoted_Inserted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs) Handles sqlvoted.Inserted
    Dim cmd As System.Data.Common.DbCommand = e.Command
    urllikeID = cmd.ExecuteScalar
End Sub
```

Am I actually running the insert twice?  Once with the sqlvoted.insert() command and once with cmd.ExecuteScalar?  That is my best guess but I don't know how to consolidate both into one.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to dispose your cmd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are calling twice

- `sqlvoted.Insert()` does an INSERT. See the [Insert method on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.insert.aspx)
- `.ExecuteScalar` does an INSERT too

Comment: Thanks, gbn.  If you don't mind, can you help me understand how to get rid of one of them?  If I remove sqlvoted.Insert() then my event handler is obsolete.  But If I remove .ExecuteScalar I don't know how else to pick up the value.   I'm on day 3 of trying to figure this out and I'm getting frustrated because I know it is something simple.  Thanks.

Comment: Move the ExecuteScalar to the EventHandler?

Comment: ExecuteScalar is already in the EventHandler, that's the problem.  Without sqlvoted.Insert() I have no event to handle, but without ExecuteScalar I don't know how to pick up the value.  This is killing me.